# If Statement to overwrite an image

Tags: php, php4

I've got a FORM Setup. The form has a current image and an option to add a new image (In place of that image)

The form fields in question are :

```
<input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="<?php echo $row_select_propertyimages['image_url']; ?>" />
<input type="file" name="new_image_url" class="inputfile" />
```

I've setup an IF Statement, to check that if new_image_url ISNT set, then to keep the current image. Otherwise, overwrite it with new_image_url. That code is as follows.

```
if(!empty($_FILES['new_image_url'])) {
    $image_url = $_POST['image_url'];
} else 
    $image_url = $_POST['new_image_url'];
```

But that is always outputting the ORIGINAL file. How can I change this to match?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get why you are using an `input type=file` for something you refer to as an url. `input type=file` is for posting contents of a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking if 'new_image_url' is NOT EMPTY, while you say you want to check if it is NOT SET. One negation too many.

```
if(empty($_FILES['new_image_url'])) {
    $image_url = $_POST['image_url'];
} else 
    $image_url = $_POST['new_image_url'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is reversed. When `new_image_url` is **not empty** you are setting `$image_url` to `$_POST['image_url']`. It should be the other way round. Basically just remove the `!`.